# Texture disappears on osx - GL_TEXTURE_2D JOGL Eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, opengl, texture2d

I have some problems with drawing textures in Eclipse.

When I run the Java application and when the window popup I only see the texture (red quads from a png.) some milliseconds then everything turns black.

I got this code and it works perfectly on all my classmates PC's but not on my Macbook Pro 2012. Run JRE 1.8.

Have changed the jogl libary to the ones for mac osx and I dont get any errors when debugging. What I can see is that there is something wrong in the drawQuad function and if I delete the row gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D) , everything draws but without the textures as u might understand, just white.

So does anyone know what the problem might be? Or is there any known bugs in osx with GL_TEXTURE_2D ?
As I wrote, the application works fine on other PC's.

Here's the class I think where the problem is:

```
private Texture texture;

void loadResources() throws GLException, IOException {
    if (texture == null)
        texture = TextureIO.newTexture(new File("3.png"), false);
}

void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    GLU glu = new GLU();

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); // reset
    glu.gluOrtho2D (0.0, w, h, 0);  // define drawing area

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); // reset
```

}

```
void drawQuad(GLAutoDrawable drawable, float x, float y, float w, float h) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE0, texture.getTarget());
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
    gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    gl.glVertex2f(x,      y);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    gl.glVertex2f(x + w, y);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    gl.glVertex2f(x + w, y + h);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    gl.glVertex2f(x,      y + h);

    gl.glEnd();

}

public void clearScreen(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

Just leave a message if u need more code.

Comment: Don't write GLU glu = new GLU(), rather use GLU.createGLU(GL). "new GLU()" should be used only in a specific case, when you're sure you don't need a feature only implemented in a subclass, for example GLUgl2.

Comment: You should rather use vertex arrays or vertex buffer objects. Let me know whether you need some examples.

Comment: If you like to write some examples that will be really good. I want to learn openGL the right way so please do :)

Comment: This example uses a static interleaved VBO: http://svn.code.sf.net/p/tuer/code/alpha/drawer/StaticVertexBufferObject.java You should look at jogl-demos too. Xerxes' example is very good and complete: http://jogamp.org/git/?p=jogl-demos.git;a=blob;f=src/demos/es2/RawGL2ES2demo.java;hb=HEAD

Comment: You can look at our wiki too: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Thanks for the links! I think its quite hard to get a grip of it though. Do you know any good guide or somewhat to get a better understanding of openGL? I have done some searches but there is hard to find the-right-way-of-doing-guide if u get me. the manual is ofc great but it also means that you should already have a reasonably experience with it.

Comment: Nevermind. Missed the wiki :D

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBindTexture.xml) glBindTexture is not allowed between glBegin and glEnd. Did you check for OpenGL errors? This should generate a GL_INVALID_OPERATION.

Edit:
According to the same here, the first parameter of glBindTexture (target) cannot be GL.GL_TEXTURE0. This should have generated a GL_INVALID_ENUM error.

Comment: I forgot to say that I tried different positions of the rows above. So even if I put the glBindTexture outside the begin and end I get the same problem.

Comment: Btw.: you are using gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 1); for two vertices. This might distort your texture, but is most probably not the problem you are facing.

Comment: Hm I dont get any errors while running, which I really should get when I read the link you gave me. Why so? Or aren't OpenGL errors displayed in the console?

Comment: They are not displayed automatically. You have to check for them with [glGetError](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glGetError.xml)

Comment: I get 1282 when I print it out in the console. I put the glGetError after the glEnd btw.

Comment: Thats the numeric value of GL_INVALID_OPERATION. Check out [this](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Error) and [that](http://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2013/01/29/debugging-opengl-using-glgeterror/)

Comment: Is this the correct use:
int err;
 while ((err = gl.glGetError()) != GL.GL_NO_ERROR) 
         System.out.println(err);
     in that case I still only get 1282 :S

Comment: Did you read the that reference? Especially the third code sample? You have to translate the error-codes yourself to readable text. But I think we are moving more and more away from the original topic.

Comment: Thanks for the links. But its really weird that the code works perfectly fine on all my classmates computers but not on mine. So if there are some openGLerrors. Why does the problem only happens to be showing up on my mac and not theirs PCs? Its exactly the same code. Same fork from github.