# JOGL Texture disappears on mac osx

Tags: macos, textures, jogl

I have done some research and cant find anyone that have the same experience of this problem.

I would appreciate if someone just can confirm that they can draw textures with eclipse and jogl running a macbook pro with JRE1.8. Or does someone else experience same problems?

[Texture disappears on osx - GL_TEXTURE_2D JOGL Eclipse java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767516/texture-disappears-on-osx-gl-texture-2d-jogl-eclipse-java/26767582?noredirect=1#comment42118517_26767582)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jmaasing (a JogAmp user) uses Oracle Java 1.8 with JOGL 2.2.4 daily on a Mac Book Pro, he ran my first person shooter at least once and he didn't reproduce this problem.

Your title is plain wrong. Sorry it's a provocation, I'm really furious. Moreover, the mistake comes from your code, read this:
https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBindTexture.xhtml

`gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE0, texture.getTarget());`????????? This is wrong. The target is the first parameter and the second one isn't the texture unit, it's the texture identifier (sometimes called the texture "object") returned by glGenTextures. GL.GL_TEXTURE0 should be used with glActiveTexture. You're lucky if it works sometimes. Rather write:

```
gl.glBindTexture(texture.getTarget(), texture.getTextureObject());
```

Good luck. Sorry to be harsh but **please read the manual**.

Edit.: You call call Texture.enable(), Texture.bind() and Texture.disable() too.

Comment: Thanks you very very much gouessej. This was the problem. Im really sorry if it sounded like a provocation. I didnt write the code. It's a example from the course we just started. Its not a specific openGL-course, so I guess thats why the code example isnt that well written. Again, thank you very much and I will read the manual :)

Comment: Please tell me which teacher wrote it then so that we can help him to fix her/his course. You're welcome. JOGL API documentation is here: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/